# How to modify QML dynamic objects from JavaScript

Tags: qt, qml

I have QML file which describes button(moduleButton.qml):

```
import QtQuick 2.0
Rectangle {
    id: button;
    width: 100; height: 20
    Text {
        id: buttonText;
        text: "Hello World";
    }
}
```

From other QML form I load this button via Qt.createComponent method:

```
var moduleButton = Qt.createComponent("moduleButton.qml");
moduleButton.createObject(mainRect);
```

I tried to set/get width of moduleButton:

```
moduleButton.width = 30;
```

But received following error: `Cannot assign to non-existent property "width"`

**How to access dynamic object attributes and child elements?**

P.S. Qt.createQmlObject method perfectly works, but I need to load QML from file, not from string.

Comment: createQmlObject

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`createObject()` returns the new object. Your code should look like this:

```
var moduleButton = Qt.createComponent("moduleButton.qml");
var myButton = moduleButton.createObject(mainRect);

myButton.width = 40
```

The moduleButton is a component (a factory), used to instantiate the item.

Documentation:
http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtqml-javascript-dynamicobjectcreation.html